# MySQL Workbench saves BOOL data types columns as TINYINT(4)

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Why does MySQL Workbench save BOOL data types columns as TINYINT(4) and not TINYINT(1)? I understand that the number between the brackets (in the case of TINYINT) is for display purposes only - so the 4 means that it can display 4 digits, so that all possible values of TINYINT (-128 to 128) fit. But that would make more sense if I were specifying a data type such as BYTE. Data type BOOL, as far as I'm concerned, would make more sense to be saved as a TINYINT(1), as a BOOL data type is normally used to refer to a Boolean value (TRUE and FALSE, or 1 and 0(. I.e. a BIT value.

Comment: Is it really MySQL Workbench or do you see an effect caused by the server? If enabled you can review a query before it's sent to the server. Does it show a BOOL or a TINYINT(4) as data type?

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for the reply. If I add a BOOL column in the latest version of Workbench, It generates the following SQL:

**ALTER TABLE `db1`.`table1` 
ADD COLUMN `column1` TINYINT NULL;**

So BOOL seems to map to TINYINT, and TINYINT seems to default to TINYINT(4)? I tried the same with SqlYog, and it generates the following query:

**ALTER TABLE `db1`.`table1` 
ADD COLUMN `column1` BOOL NULL;**

This, however, creates a TINYINT(1)

So I guess TINYINT becomes TINYINT(4) and BOOL becomes TINYINT(1)?

Comment: Ok, then it doesn't seem to be WB. What do you get back when you now do a SHOW CREATE TABLE?

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html BOOL is just an alias for TINYINT(1), but I can't see why either WB or the server would return TINYINT(4) for it.